# not in query and select one field from second collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My requirement is to count all the data whose particular `id` is not in reference collection. The equivalent `SQL` query would go as below:

```
select count(*) from tbl1 where tbl.arr.id not in (select id from tbl2)
```

I've tried as below, but got stuck up on fetching single field i.e. `id` from 2nd query.

```
db.coll1.find(
        {$not:
            {"arr.id":
                 {$in:
                       {db.coll2.find()}//how would I fetch a single column from 
                                       //2nd coll2
                 }
            }
        }
).count()
```

Also, Please note that `arr.id` is an `ObjectId` stored in collection `coll1` and same will go with collection `coll2`. Should special care be taken while fetching the `id` like say `ObjectId(id)`?

**Update** - I am using mongo db **version 3.0.9**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use **[`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)** to check for `not in` condition and get the array in a different format as the version of `mongodb` was `3.0.9`. Below is how I did it.

```
db.coll1.find({"arr.id":{$nin:[db.coll2.find({},["id"])]}}).count()
```

For `mongodb v>=3.2` it would be as below

```
db.coll1.find({"arr.id":{$nin:[db.coll2.find({},"id")]}}).count()
```